# Using postgres generate_series to generate a recurring schedule

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, generate-series

I have a table with recurring dates called `Events`, how can I take this table and generate the specific upcoming dates from a series based on the events wday and time? (eg only wday "mondays" and start time "7pm" are important)

## Event

```
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
| id  | start_at                  | recurring_schedule  |
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 358 | 2015-01-23 20:00:00 +0000 | Weekly              |
| 359 | 2016-01-22 19:30:00 +1100 | Monthly             |
| 360 | 2016-02-01 19:00:00 +1100 | Weekly              |
| 361 | 2016-02-01 20:00:00 +0000 | Weekly              |
| 362 | 2014-02-13 20:00:00 +0000 | Bi-Weekly           |
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

- start_at (date time, used for the DOW and start time, actual date is ignored)

For simplicity you can ignore the recurring schedule and just assume all events are weekly, eg always on the same day of the week.

How can I take a table like this and convert it into something like this:

## FutureLog

```
+----------+---------------------------+
| event_id | start_at                  |
+----------+---------------------------+
| 35       | 2018-04-11 19:30:00 +0000 |
| 94       | 2018-04-12 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 269      | 2018-04-13 18:30:00 +0100 |
| 45       | 2018-04-13 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 242      | 2018-04-13 19:30:00 +1100 |    
| 35       | 2018-04-18 19:30:00 +0000 |
| 94       | 2018-04-19 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 269      | 2018-04-20 18:30:00 +0100 |
| 45       | 2018-04-20 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 242      | 2018-04-20 19:30:00 +1100 |
+----------+---------------------------+
```

Eg I want to `SELECT FROM events` the theoretical events and create 6-8 weeks of future dates from each event using something like generate_series to build a timeline of events.

Comment: simple json i believe, but you can ignore it, for this example you could assume they're recurring every week at the same time on the same day, eg every monday at 7:30pm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

updated answer:

Use generate_series within a case statement to build sequences similarly to ohw I did it in my original answer, with varying frequencies based on the column `recurring_schedule`.

Specify the date you want the series to generate as an absolute date `'2020-01-01'::timestamptz` as I've used below, of you can pass a relative date, e.g. `NOW() + INTERVAL '10 weeks'` instead.

```
SELECT id event_id, start_at, 
CASE recurring_schedule 
    WHEN 'Weekly' 
        THEN GENERATE_SERIES(start_at, '2020-01-01'::timestamptz, '1 weeks'::INTERVAL)
    WHEN 'Bi-Weekly'
        THEN GENERATE_SERIES(start_at, '2020-01-01'::timestamptz, '2 weeks'::INTERVAL)
    WHEN 'Monthly'
        THEN GENERATE_SERIES(start_at, '2020-01-01'::timestamptz, '1 month'::INTERVAL)
    ELSE NULL 
END recurring_start_time
FROM events;
```

original answer for schema with json fields:

the syntax for generate_series for datetime types is

```
generate_series(start_time, end_time, step_interval)
```

Since your schedule is in JSON contains the interval, you could construct the query as such, and add more schedule types as required.

```
WITH test (id, start_at, place_id, recurring_schedule) AS (

VALUES 
(358, '2015-01-23 20:00:00 +0000'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 412, 
'{"validations":{"day":[2]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0}'::JSONB),

(359, '2016-01-22 19:30:00 +1100', 414,
'{"validations":{"day":[1]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0}'),

(360, '2016-02-01 19:00:00 +1100', 415, 
'{"validations":{"day":[4]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0}'),

(361, '2016-02-01 20:00:00 +0000', 416, 
'{"validations":{"day":[4]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0}'),

(362, '2014-02-13 20:00:00 +0000', 417,
'{"validations":{"day":[2]},"rule_type":"IceCube::WeeklyRule","interval":1,"week_start":0}')
)
SELECT id, start_at, place_id, 
CASE recurring_schedule->>'rule_type' 
    WHEN 'IceCube::WeeklyRule' 
        THEN GENERATE_SERIES(start_at, NOW(), (recurring_schedule->>'interval' || ' WEEK')::INTERVAL)
    ELSE NULL 
END recurring_start_time
FROM test;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use this as a nested query, eg `SELECT from events` instead of `WITH`?

Comment: i'm not sure i follow what you're confused about. the with clause is just putting sample data in a view called `test`. the actual query starts with `SELECT id, start_at, place_id, ...`. Replace `From test` with `FROM events`

Comment: I have updated the question to make it less complex.  Sorry, I wasn't more clear before.

Comment: last question, how can I also convert the start_at date in the series to be the same WDAY but from the current week (or upcoming)?  eg 2013-01-01 -> 2018-04-24 (tues)

Comment: e.g. I only care about the WDAY from the start_at column, not the actual date, I'm only interested in it's relative value on current future dates.

Comment: please update your question with the appropriate details and example. future readers of this post should not be expected to read through the comments to find the motivation for the solution